# Async wait till variable is set in the display template

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, display-template

I have a problem with excuting the script in the right order. I have a custom.js which is loaded at the top of the masterpage. The following function is included:

```
var results;    
var followers;
function OnSuccess()
{
     function excuted()
     {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var counts = 0;
    clientContext.load(peopleFollowingMe);
    var test = results.getEnumerator();
    while (test.moveNext()) {
    var person = test.get_current();
        followers.push(person.get_displayName());
        counts++;
    }
    $("#followersCount").text('(' + counts + ')');
    console.debug(followers);
    }
}

function getFollowers()
{
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

     // Get the people who are following the current user.
     peopleFollowingMe = peopleManager.getMyFollowers();

     clientContext.load(peopleFollowingMe);
     results = peopleFollowingMe;
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess, requestFailed)
}
```

No matter what i tru the getFollowers is always excuted later then the controller of the display template where i say the following:

```
if(followers.indexOf(encodedName) > -1)
```

What did i try?

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded
```

Also i tried putting the whole output in a function(html output) in the excuted but it won't help.

So how do i let the display template wait till the followers variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how to use promises with executeQueryAsync from this page: http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2013/10/31/using-jquery-promises-deferreds-with-sharepoint-2013-jsom/.

```
function successCallback() {
    this.d.resolve(this.list);
}

function failCallback() {
    this.d.reject("something bad happened");
}

function getList(name) {
    var d = $.Deferred();

    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(name);

    var o = {d: d, list:list};
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(o, successCallback), Function.createDelegate(o, failCallback));

    return d.promise();
}

var p = getList("Documents");
p.done(function(result) {
    // result is an SP.List because that is what we passed to resolve()!
    var list = result;
    // do something with the list
});
p.fail(function(result) {
    // result is a string because that is what we passed to reject()!
    var error = result;
    console.log(error);
});
```